# Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me this:

I want to group by column TestType, but Result should be splitted into colunms if they have same TestType

```
CREATE TABLE Result(WorkOrder varchar(10), TestType varchar(20), Result decimal(10,2));
INSERT INTO Result (WorkOrder, TestType, Result) VALUES 
('HP19002316','VitaminA', 10.3),
('HP19002316','VitaminA', 11.3),
('HP19002316','VitaminA', 12.3),
('HP19002316','VitaminB', 13.4),
('HP19002316','VitaminB', 14.4),
('HP19002316','VitaminC', 15.5),
('HP19002316','VitaminD', 17.0)
```

I want SQL to return data in this format

```
WorkOrder       TestType        Result1   Result2  Result3 
==========================================================
HP19002316      VitaminA        10.3        11.3    12.3    
HP19002316      VitaminB        13.4        14.4    NULL
HP19002316      VitaminC        15.5        NULL    NULL
HP19002316      VitaminD        17.0        NULL    NULL
```

Result# column should be dynamic because each TestType has many Results

Comment: Answer: You need dynamic SQL if you want the number of columns to be variable.  Regular SQL cannot do this.

Comment: "I want" isn't a question. What is it you need help with? What about *your* attempts didn't work? What *are* your attempts?

Comment: Also what in your data denotes what is "Result1", "Result2" and "Result3"? You have no always ascending key, so what determines the "order"?

Comment: What you are after here, however, is called a Pivot or Cross tab (conditional aggregation). Most likely this would be combined with `ROW_NUMBER`. As @TimBiegeleisen suggests, you would need dynamic SQL too if a `TestType` has an indeterminable maximum number of rows.

Comment: Thanks guys, 

Before the post, I have tried with dynamic SQL and pivot but didn't help. It is much appreciated if you have any guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your attempts, @PeterNguyNguyen . And don't forget to answer the questions we've asked you above; such as how you determine the order and if there is a determinable number of rows.

Comment: Note, if you have no way to determine the order the best you could hope for would be any arbitrary order; so the results could easily be different each time you run the query.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, thank you for your recommendations, no need to determine the order

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, what you need here is a `PIVOT` or Cross tab; I prefer the latter so what I am going to use.

The non-dynamic solution to this would be as follows:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT WorkOrder,
           TestType,
           Result,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WorkOrder, TestType ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --ORDER BY should be your ID/always ascending column
    FROM dbo.Result)
SELECT WorkOrder,
       TestType,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Result END) AS Result1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN Result END) AS Result2,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN Result END) AS Result3
FROM RNs R
GROUP BY WorkOrder,
         TestType;
```

The problem, however, is that this "locks" you into 3 results, but you suggest there is an indeterminate number of results. Therefore you need a dynamic solution.

The below will work up to 100 results. if you do *need* more columns than than, then add more `CROSS JOIN`s to `N` in the CTE `Tally`. This results is something like this (which is quite messy).

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @MaxTally int;

SELECT @MaxTally = MAX(C)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C
      FROM dbo.Result
      GROUP BY WorkOrder,
               TestType) R;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@MaxTally) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --100 rows, add more Ns for more rows
SELECT @SQL = N'WITH RNs AS(' + @CRLF +
              N'    SELECT WorkOrder,' + @CRLF +
              N'           TestType,' + @CRLF +
              N'           Result,' + @CRLF +
              N'           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WorkOrder, TestType ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --ORDER BY should be your ID/always ascending column' + @CRLF +
              N'    FROM dbo.Result)' + @CRLF +
              N'SELECT WorkOrder,' + @CRLF +
              N'       TestType,' + @CRLF +
              --Using FOR XML PATH due to not knowing SQL Server version
              STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                            CONCAT(N'       MAX(CASE RN WHEN ',T.I,N' THEN Result END) AS Result',T.I)
                     FROM Tally T
                     ORDER BY T.I ASC
                     FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
              N'FROM RNs R' + @CRLF +
              N'GROUP BY WorkOrder,' + @CRLF +
              N'         TestType;';

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this and extend the logic.

```
select *,((select Result from (select TestType,Result, ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION BY testtype ORDER BY  Testtype) Id from Result) a where a.Id='1' and a.TestType=b.TestType )) Result1,
((select Result from (select TestType,Result, ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION BY testtype ORDER BY  Testtype) Id from Result) a where a.Id='2' and a.TestType=b.TestType )) Result2,
((select Result from (select TestType,Result, ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION BY testtype ORDER BY  Testtype) Id from Result) a where a.Id='3' and a.TestType=b.TestType )) Result3
 from (
select Max(WorkOrder) WorkOrder,TestType from Result group by TestType ) b
```

Comment: Using a sub query for each result seems like overkill here. This results in 4 scans of the table for just 3 columns, and doesn't scale as more results are added.