# Swapping rows and columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make city1, city2, city3 lines as columns. Likewise, I want to display numerical values ​​horizontally.

I shared the original painting:

[Original painting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtJcH.jpg)

Table detail:

```
create table table_name
(
    id int identity,
    city nvarchar(10),
    The_number_of_customers int
)
```

This is the output I want:

```
city name 1 | city name 2 | city name 3 | city name 4 |
------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
   60       |     75      |     150     |     125     |
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521960/2029983)

Comment: If you know the relevant cities in advance, you can use the pivot technique: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: I reached the conclusion with the pivot technique. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good case vor pivot:

```
DECLARE @table_name table (
id int,
city nvarchar(1060),
The_number_of_customers int
)

INSERT INTO @table_name VALUES
(1, 'city name 1', 60)
,(2, 'city name 2', 75)
,(3, 'city name 3', 150)
,(4, 'city name 4', 125)

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT city, The_number_of_customers
    FROM @table_name
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte t
PIVOT
(
 MAX(t.The_number_of_customers) FOR city IN ([city name 1], [city name 2], [city name 3], [city name 4])
) AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select max(case when city = 'city name1' then The_number_of_customers  end) as "city name 1",
       max(case when city = 'city name2' then The_number_of_customers  end) as "city name 2",
       max(case when city = 'city name3' then The_number_of_customers  end) as "city name 3",
       max(case when city = 'city name4' then The_number_of_customers  end) as "city name 4"
  from table_name
```