# Creating separate columns based on the main column in a sql table.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with thousands of record which has a structure like below :

| Street | House | Persons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | B | 5 |
| 1 | C | 3 |
| 2 | D | 6 |
| 2 | E | 9 |
| 3 | F | 4 |

I want to frame a sql query such that its output will be like:

| Street | House | Persons | House | Persons | House | Persons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 | B | 5 | C | 3 |
| 2 | D | 6 | E | 9 | null | null |
| 3 | F | 4 | null | null | null | null |

The number of house in a street is not the same for all the streets and it varies based on the street.
Can someone please help me in framing this query? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when someone has 4 houses? Or 5? 7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63521138/2029983)

Comment: It is the number of houses in a street and how many houses a person owns is not relevant here. If a street has 4/5/6 houses that many number of columns have to be added.

Comment: That comment contradicts itself; if it doesn't matter then the result would "cap" at 3 sets, and the rest wouldn't matter.

Comment: What I meant is for example if there is a house G in street 1 with 8 persons in that house then the resulting table should have another house and person column under street 1 with house name as G and persons as 8. I hope my explanation is understandable.

Comment: Yes, which means that how many houses there can be *does* matter... You need dynamic SQL for this; see the answer I linked above. This, however, isn't simple logic and I would urge you not going down this path at all.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link. I am trying to understand your dynamic solution. I too wish to not go down this path but unfortunately I don't have an option.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed maximum number of rows per street, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select street,
    max(case when rn = 1 then house   end) as house1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then persons end) as persons1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then house   end) as house2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then persons end) as persons2
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by street order by house) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by street
```

You can add more conditional expressions to the `select` clause to handle more rows per street.