# SQL How to Pivot Dynamic Rows from Lookup Table into Columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a lookup table that is maintained every other time and is populated with drivers to display in a report. The table looks like this:

| Department | Driver |
| --- | --- |
| Store | Driver-1 |
| Store | Driver-2 |
| Store | Driver-3 |

I need the output to comeout as this:

```
Driver-1|Driver-2|Driver-3
```

This code produces a string of drivers enclosed in square brackets and seperated by commas

```sql
declare @driverList varchar(max)
set @driverList = ''
SELECT @driverList = @driverList + '[' + driver + '],' FROM MY_STAGED_DRIVERS_TABLE
select substring (@driverList, 1, (len(@driverList) - 1))
```

And outputs this as a string:

```
[Driver-1],[Driver-2],[Driver-3].....[Driver-n]
```

i need help with SQL that will pivot these drivers into columns. I dont want to use dynamic sql, i need another solution that works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: *"I dont want to use dynamic sql"* If you want a solution using SQL, impossible with the requirements you have provided and the data you imply you have (as I explain in the suggestion duplicate).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks but it seems to hard code the results. I wanted it to use the same logic of using row numbers but outputting the value of that row from the lookup table into the column. I dont know if this makes sense?

Comment: What seems to hard code the results, @Lavie ? If you mean the linked duplicate, the non-dynamic one does, yes, because it's not dynamic. The Dynamic one doesn't, but to get dynamic results you (surprise!) have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Also, what are you expecting the values to be in these columns? You say you want to pivot them into columns, but the columns have the name of the driver as their alias, so what should be the column's value? The value of `Department`?

Comment: So in the lookup table the drivers are captured in rows per department, so I need to just extract the drivers, which are named already and pivot them into columns, then later in my interface i will use these columns to append to a file with monetary values

Comment: *"and pivot them into columns"* Yes, but you're going to have at least 1 row, why is the value in said row(s)? All we have is that you want a column called `Driver-1`; but there (I assume( will need to be at least one row.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I just want 1 row of drivers, driver 1 to driver n from my lookup table. Let me try the dynamic sql and I will let you know if it solves my problem for now

Comment: @Larnu could be done if there is a hard maximum

Comment: Not when they  need dynamic names for the columns, per their expected results, @Charlieface .

Comment: @Larnu What, you can just do `'Driver-' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()...`?

Comment: @Charlieface If there is a way that I can do it with say a maximum of 20 columns i would appreciate it. Just take note that these drivers are manually captured in a table, then if the user decides to rename any of the drivers i need the SQL to pick the correct names from that table and while converting them to columns

Comment: You can't do `AS YT.DriverName` though, @Charlieface . You can't use a column's value to define the alias of it. That can only be done with Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Larnu True, sorry I only got the `Driver-1/n` bit. It is a solution I've used many times if I just want a row number

Comment: If it was just the row number, yes, it would work; the OP's last comment (*"then if the user decides to rename any of the drivers i need the SQL to pick the correct names from that table and while converting them to columns"*) only further confirms that isn't what they are after, @Charlieface , and that they want the colum's name to be the driver's name. That requires dynamic SQL, unfortunately. To be honset, this is probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to help, so far my solution is bringing back a string in 1 column like this [Driver-1],[Driver-2],[Driver-3]. could there be an easier way to split this string into columns. I have tried using an inbuilt function splitString but with no joy

Comment: Best bet is to return data as it is supposed to be, **normalized** into rows, and convert it in display client-side. Columns headers should not be part of the data, they hsould be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off by addressing this statement:

> I dont want to use dynamic sql, i need another solution that works

*If* you an indeterminate number of drivers, as I have mentioned in the comments, you **need** to use dynamic SQL. There's no way round that; you can't have non-dynamic SQL that results a dynamic number of columns that's not how the language works.

As you haven't mentioned what version of SQL Server you're using, I'm going to *assume* you're on a more recent version and thus have access to `STRING_AGG`. If not, you'll need to use the older `FOR XML PATH` method. As you don't define what the value in the row should be, I've guessed it should be the department's name

This gives the something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Department varchar(10),
                            Driver varchar(10));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('Store','Driver-1'),
      ('Store','Driver-2'),
      ('Store','Driver-3');
GO

DECLARE @Dept varchar(10) = 'Store';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(30) = N',' + @CRLF + N'       ';

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(N'Department AS ' + QUOTENAME(Driver),@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Driver ASC) + @CRLF +
              N'FROM dbo.YourTable YT' + @CRLF +
              N'WHERE Department = @Dept' + @CRLF +
              N'GROUP BY Department;'
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE Department = @Dept;

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Dept varchar(10)', @Dept;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1000cdc4288fe3a1d53549282954a1ee)