# Group and expand to new columns using a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Having this data:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-03-01 10:00 |
| Paul | 2021-03-01 11:00 |
| Paul | 2021-03-01 14:20 |
| John | 2021-03-01 15:00 |
| Paul | 2021-03-01 17:00 |

How can I obtain this result (Dates ordered ASC)

| Name | Date1 | Date2 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2021-03-01 10:00 | 2021-03-01 15:00 | NULL |
| Paul | 2021-03-01 11:00 | 2021-03-01 14:20 | 2021-03-01 17:00 |

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63521138/2029983) If not, why not?

Comment: Probably. I searched but did not found that question/answer. Thank you.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I have SQL Server 2014 and 2017 installed

Answer (score 1):

Based on Larnu's help, This worked:

```
  WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT       [Name],
          [DateTime],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Punch
    WHERE Date = '2016-04-18'
    )
SELECT Name,
    
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN [DateTime] END) AS Result1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN [DateTime] END) AS Result2,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN [DateTime] END) AS Result3,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN [DateTime] END) AS Result4

FROM RNs R
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your query dynamic that means no matter how many dates you have for any given name this query will generate that number of columns automatically try below query:

Schema:

```
 create table mytable (Name     varchar(50),[Date] Datetime);
 
 insert into mytable values('John' , '2021-03-01 10:00');
 insert into mytable values('Paul' , '2021-03-01 11:00');
 insert into mytable values('Paul' , '2021-03-01 14:20');
 insert into mytable values('John' , '2021-03-01 15:00');
 insert into mytable values('Paul' , '2021-03-01 17:00');
```

Query:

```
 declare @cols  as varchar(max), @colsForSelect as varchar(max), @query as varchar(max);
 
 select @colsForSelect=string_agg(concat(quotename(rn),' ', datename),',' )from(
 select distinct concat('Date',rn) datename,rn from
 (SELECT row_number()over(partition by name order by [date])rn from mytable)t)a
 
 select @cols =string_agg(quotename(rn),',') from (
 select distinct rn from
 (SELECT row_number()over(partition by name order by [date])rn from mytable)t)a
 
 set @query = 'Select Name, ' + @colsForSelect + ' from 
             (
                SELECT *,row_number()over(partition by name order by [date])rn 
                from mytable
             ) x
             pivot 
             (
                 max([date])
                 for rn in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p 
             group by Name,' + @cols 
  
 execute(@query);
```

Output:

> | Name | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | John | 2021-03-01 10:00:00.000 | 2021-03-01 15:00:00.000 | *null* |
> | Paul | 2021-03-01 11:00:00.000 | 2021-03-01 14:20:00.000 | 2021-03-01 17:00:00.000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29ba0b3172b2bfd79aadc3af72e1b560)*

Comment: That can be usefull too. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome. But if number of date is fixed then your query will run much faster than this one.

Comment: Thanks for the question. It was nice one. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with Stuff function instead of sting_agg which was introduced in 2017 server. If you are using below 2017 version you can use the below query.

```
declare @column_name varchar(5000)
declare @col_name varchar(5000)

set @column_name = (select stuff((select  ','+'['+cast(rn as varchar(1000))+']' from(select distinct row_number()over(partition by name order by (select null))as rn from mytable)a
for xml path('')), 1,1,''))

set @col_name = (select stuff((select  ','+'['+cast(rn as varchar(1000))+']' +' Date'+cast(rn as varchar(1000)) from(select distinct row_number()over(partition by name order by (select null))as rn from mytable)a
for xml path('')), 1,1,'')) 

exec('select name, '+@col_name +'
from (
select  row_number()over(partition by name order by (select null))rn, year([date]) yr, *
from mytable
)a
pivot
(
max([date]) for  [rn]  in ('+@column_name+' )
)pv')
```