# Displaying a multiple columns in single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select ID,POLICY_ID,CONTACT_ID,POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION  BY POLICY_ID,POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE ORDER BY ID ) AS ORDERNO
FROM P_POL_HEADER_CONTACT ) SUB
WHERE SUB.ORDERNO=1 AND POLICY_ID =20001
```

I want to arrange the above query to take result like this

[image: My Result]

[image: My aim]

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use images - use formatted text.

Comment: Why are there 2 `Policy_Contact_Role2` columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pivot on a row-number.**

You can use `PIVOT`, but I often find a simple `GROUP BY/MAX` is simpler, especially when you need to rename the columns.

```sql
SELECT
    SUB.POLICY_ID
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_NO = 1 THEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE END) AS POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_NO = 2 THEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE END) AS POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE2
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_NO = 3 THEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE END) AS POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE3
    -- etc etc
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY POLICY_ID ORDER BY POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE) AS POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_NO
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY POLICY_ID, POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE ORDER BY ID ) AS ORDERNO
        FROM P_POL_HEADER_CONTACT
        WHERE POLICY_ID = 20001
    ) SUB
    WHERE SUB.ORDERNO = 1
) SUB
GROUP BY SUB.POLICY_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation.  I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT PCH.POLICY_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 1 THEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE END) as POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 2 THEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE END) as POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 3 THEN POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE END) as POLICY_CONTACT_ROLE_3
FROM (SELECT PHC.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY POLICY_ID ORDER BY ID ) AS SEQNUM
      FROM P_POL_HEADER_CONTACT PHC
     ) PHC
WHERE POLICY_ID = 20001
GROUP BY POLICY_ID;
```

I'm not sure what your filtering on `ORDERNO` is really doing.  If you have duplicates, use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.  However, without knowing what your data looks like, I am guessing that is unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

Exclude CONTACT_ID from query. And use STUFF query to convert your rows into columns