# Transpose a table with multiple ID rows and different assessment dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas

I would like to transpose my table to see trends in a data. The data is formatted as such:

UserId is can occur multiple times because of different assessment periods. Let's say a user with ID 1 inccured some charges in January, February, and March. There are currently three rows that contain data from these periods respectively.

I would like to see everything as one row - independently of the number of periods (up to 12 months), for each user ID.
This would enable me to see and compare changes between assessment periods and attributes.

Current format:

```
UserId AssessmentDate                   Attribute1 Attribute2 Attribute3
1      2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 -01:00   20.13      123.11     405.00
1      2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 -01:00   1.03       78.93      11.34
1      2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 -01:00   15.03      310.10     23.15

2      2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 -01:00   14.31      41.30      63.20
2      2021-03-01 00:03:45.000 -01:00   0.05       3.50       1.30
```

Desired format:

```
   UserId LastAssessmentDate               Attribute1_M-2 Attribute2_M-1 ... Attribute3_M0
   1      2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 -01:00   20.13          123.11             23.15
   2      2021-03-01 00:03:45.000 -01:00   NULL           41.30              1.30
```

Either SQL or Pandas - both work for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: What aggregate do you want to use? How are  you choosing which value to use in each column?