# Expand Col values based on names/email SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to explode my table based on their 'KEY's and assort their names and emails separately into individual cols.

In Python such scenarios are dealt easily(like we use explode in pandas). since I've just started with SQL I'm finding it difficult to get my feet wet. My googling didn't help me even next to were i want, hence reaching out to the community as a my last resort for some guidance. In essence i'm trying to expand my table with my KEY as the index and the names and emails exploded across multiple cols.

my table:

| KEY | FIRST | MIDDLE | LAST | EMAIL | FLAG_GENDER | FLAG_DESCENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ROBIN | A | SIMPSON | ROBIN@PROTON.COM | M | - |
| 1 | NICOLE | P | SIMPOSON | NIC@YAHOO.COM | F | NA |
| 1 | SANDY |  | LAYNE |  | F | NA |
| 1 | BRUCE |  | NILLS | BRUCENILLS@ | M | NA |
| 1 | ERIC |  | WOOTEN | ERICW@YAHOO.COM | M | NA |
| 5 | JUDY |  | THAMES | JUDYTHAMES@YAHOO.COM | F | NA |
| 5 | JUDY |  | THAMES | JUDY@GMAIL.COM | F | NA |
| A290 | RENN | J | JOHNSON | RENNY@COMCAST.COM | M | C |
| K890 | JAMES |  | RODRIGUES | NA | M | L |
| 189 | BECKIE | KATE | MOORS | BECKIE@GMAIL.COM | F | - |
| 189 | BECKIE |  |  | MOORSB@YAHOO.COM | F | - |
| 189 |  |  | MOORS | BMOORS@GMAIL.COM | F | - |
| 189 | BECKIE | KATE | MOORS | BECKIE@GMAIL.COM | F | - |

output table:

| KEY | FULL NAME_1 | FULL NAME_2 | FULL NAME_3 | FULL NAME_4 | FULL NAME_5 | EMAIL_1 | EMAIL_2 | EMAIL_3 | EMAIL_4 | EMAIL_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ROBIN A SIMPSON | NICOLE P SIMPOSON | SANDY LAYNE | BRUCE NILLS | ERIC WOOTEN | ROBIN@PROTON.COM | NIC@YAHOO.COM | NA | BRUCENILLS@ | ERICW@YAHOO.COM |
| 5 | JUDY THAMES | JUDY THAMES |  |  |  | JUDYTHAMES@YAHOO.COM | JUDY@GMAIL.COM |  |  |  |
| A290 | RENN J JOHNSON |  |  |  |  | RENNY@COMCAST.COM |  |  |  |  |
| K890 | JAMES RODRIGUES |  |  |  |  | NA |  |  |  |  |
| 189 | BECKIE KATE MOORS | BECKIE MOORS | MOORS | BECKIE KATE MOORS |  | BECKIE@GMAIL.COM | MOORSB@YAHOO.COM | BMOORS@GMAIL.COM | BECKIE@GMAIL.COM |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: It's very close but still bit opaque.

Comment: Why does it not? I am very confident it does, as what you are after appears to be exactly what my answer in the dupe candidate does.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, the KEY field in your answer is repeated many times and the pivot is taken for just the 'Result' field. Here i guess it's double the job

Comment: The actual solution is identical. Instead of condition aggregation on (just) `Result`, you just have conditional aggregation `FullName` and `Email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my comments, I strongly suggest that this is a duplicate of [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns) however, to demonstrate how you would do it for 2 columns, instead of 1:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT [KEY], --KEY is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object names.
           STUFF(CONCAT(' ' + [FIRST], ' ' + MIDDLE, ' ' + [LAST]),1,1,'') AS FullName, --FIRST and LAST are reserved ODBC keywords and should be avoided for object names.
           --If you're on 2017+ you can use CONCAT_WS:
           --CONCAT_WS(' ',[FIRST], MIDDLE, [LAST]) AS FullName,
           Email,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [KEY] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --ORDER BY should be your ID/always ascending column --KEY is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object names.
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT [KEY], --KEY is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object names.
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN FullName END) AS FullName1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN FullName END) AS FullName2,
       ...
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Email END) AS Email1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN Email END) AS Email2,
       ...
FROM RNs R
GROUP BY [KEY]; --KEY is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object names.
```

If you need a dynamic solution, that too is demonstrated in the linked duplicate candidate; the principle again is the same.

Comment: This query is giving me incorrect results. All the names and emails are distributed across the fields from name1...5 and emails from email1...5 without checking the condition. Ex: ID: K890, the name is same for all the name fields same goes with the email too. ideally the name should be dropped just to the fullname1 field and name2..5 should be null.

Comment: I don't get the same values in all the columns, @New_here [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7815ff3a62a1ee2aa29ec3554cb145e6). That suggests you've change the answer some how, or not expanded it properly for each column (you need to change the `WHEN` clause for each column).

Comment: I wouldn't call this just the right solution, Your query above is sql art, amazing!! Thank you much. Got a question mate, you mentioned about the dynamic soln. What is the significance of the dyn query over this one?

Comment: The one above is a "static" solution, it'll generate as many column as you define, @New_here . A dynamic solution will generate as many columns as you *need*. So, in the fiddle I provided, you would only get 2 columns for Full name and email, even if there were 5 rows with the same ID; the others would be "lost". If you have an upper limit (5 in your sample data) then code for 5. If it's an indeterminable amount of rows, you might want a dynamic solution (which I also demonstrate in the suggested duplicate).

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you. You're very kind and helpful!! Appreciate you much