# Retrieve multiple rows into single row based on FK SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have the following table:

| ID_TableDetails | FK_TableMaster | StartDate | EndDate | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-24 | 2021-05-24 | 10:00 | 11:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-05-25 | 2021-05-25 | 10:00 | 11:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-05-26 | 2021-05-26 | 11:00 | 12:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-05-27 | 2021-05-27 | 11:00 | 12:00 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-05-28 | 2021-05-28 | 11:00 | 12:00 |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-05-29 | 2021-05-29 | 11:00 | 12:00 |

I want to select values from the above table in the following manner

| 1stID | 2ndID | 3rdID | 1stStartDte | 1stStartTimeEndTime | 2ndStartDte | 2ndStartTimeEndTime | 3rdStartDte | 3rdStartTimeEndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-05-24 | 10:00 TO 11:00 | 2021-05-25 | 10:00 TO 11:00 | 2021-05-26 | 11:00 TO 12:00 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 2021-05-24 | 10:00 TO 11:00 | 2021-05-25 | 10:00 TO 11:00 | 2021-05-26 | 11:00 TO 12:00 |

There will always be three entries for `FK_TableMaster` and I want to select is as one row.

This is what I have tried

```sql
SELECT 
    ID_TableDetils, Description, Startate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime  
FROM 
    TableDetils AS TD
JOIN 
    TableMaster AS TM ON TD.ID_TableDetils = TM.FK_TableMaster
```

This will return multiple rows for `FK_TableMaster` - I don't know how to select it as a single row any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE based on :[Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

```
WITH RNs AS
(
   SELECT ID_TableDetails,
          FK_TableMaster,
          StartDate,
          EndDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PtaEventScheduleDetails, FK_PtaEventSchedule ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --ORDER BY should be your ID/always ascending column
   FROM dbo.TableDetails 
   WHERE Cancelled = 0 AND FK_TableMaster = 1
)
SELECT 
    ID_TableDetails,
    FK_TableMaster,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN StartDate END) AS Result1,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN StartDate END) AS Result2,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN StartDate END) AS Result3,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN EndDate END) AS Result4,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN EndDate END) AS Result5,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN EndDate END) AS Result6
FROM 
    RNs R
GROUP BY 
    ID_TableDetails, FK_TableMaster
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: @Larnu No this approach doesn't suit my requirement

Comment: Why not? I would suggest it does. You want to pivot on the row number; that's literally what you want to do here. [Edit] your question to explain why the dupe candidate doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Larnu It's still returning multiple rows for ***Fk*** while grouping

Comment: Then you implement the wrong `GROUP BY`.

Comment: i will add the code i have tried

Comment: You want 1 row per value `FK_TableMaster` *not* per `FK_TableMaster` and `ID_TableDetails`. `ID_TableDetails` should not be in your `GROUP BY`/`PARTITION BY`.

Comment: @Larnu Got it to thank you! I have a lot to learn in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* a duplicate of the proposed dupe candidate [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)  but to post the same answer again, replacing the columns from my other answer with the OP's:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT ID_TableDetails,
           FK_TableMaster,
           StartDate,
           EndDate,
           StartTime,
           EndTime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FK_TableMaster ORDER BY ID_TableDetails) AS RN 
    FROM dbo.Result)
SELECT MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN ID_TableDetails END) AS ID1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN ID_TableDetails END) AS ID2,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN ID_TableDetails END) AS ID3,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN StartDate END) AS StartDate1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN StartTime END) AS StartTime1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN EndTime END) AS EndTime1,
       ... --You get the idea
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN EndTime END) AS EndTime3
FROM RNs R
GROUP BY FK_TableMaster;
```