# Is it possible to recursively combine similar records (keeping - and adding - only specific columns) using a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been wracking my brain here trying to figure out a way to achieve a solution to the following without external applications (such as Excel).

I'll set up the structure: We are using a 3rd party ERP that provides a nicely configured conversion system for product packaging types. I'm trying to create a query that will take all conversions for a given product and return them inline. Because the number of conversion records is indeterminate, the query would need to be recursive.

To make things simple, let's use package quantites for this scenario example. If a product can be shipped in [*eaches*, *pairs*, *sets*, *packages*, and *cartons*], the conversion table records would look something like this:

| pkConvKey | fkProdID | childUnit | parentUnit | chPerParent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ConvRec001 | Prod123 | each | pair | 2 |
| ConvRec002 | Prod123 | pair | set | 3 |
| ConvRec003 | Prod123 | set | pack | 7 |
| ConvRec004 | Prod123 | pack | carton | 24 |

Using the table above, I can determine how many *pairs* of Prod123 are contained in a carton by following the math:

*24 packs x 7 sets x 3 pairs = 504 pairs per carton.*

I could further multiply that by 2 to get the count of individual pieces in a carton (1,008). That's the idea behind the conversion table but here's my actual problem.

I'd like to return a table of records where associated conversions are in-line, thusly:

| fkProdID | unit1 | unit2 | qtyInUnit2 | unit3 | qtyInUnit3 | unit4 | qtyInUnit4 | unit5 | qtyInUnit5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prod123 | each | pair | 2 | set | 3 | pack | 7 | carton | 24 |

Complicating the matter is that the unit types are unknown (arbitrary) values and there is no requirement to have a full, intact chain from unit A to unit Z. (For example, there might be a conversion record from *each* to *pair*, and another from set to *pack*, but not one from *pair* to *set*).

In this scenario, the select can't recursively link the records, and they would appear in the resulting table as two separate records - which is fine.

I have attempted to join the table to itself on `t1.parentUnit = t2.childUnit`, but that obviously doesn't work recursively.

I fear my only solution is to `left join` the table over and over - as many as 20 times in the query, settling for `NULL` values if additional conversions do not exist but then I would also have many duplicate rows (with incomplete conversion chains) to weed out.

Can this be done in a select query?

Thanks in advance!

-Dan

Comment: No, this cannot be done with a simple `select`, because a `select` must clearly define the columns being returned.

Comment: You would have to use a dynamic pivot. Personally, I would suggest reconsidering your decision to want/need this.

Comment: If you *"must"* go down this path, this will answer your question: [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. For some clarity, the underlying requirement stems from our need to port item conversion data to [yet another] 3rd party vendor's ERP. Their conversion functionality relies on in-line conversions within the product record itself, as opposed to using a separate conversion table. I have offered my opinion (read: experience) that a separate conversion table is preferable over inline values in a single record, if for no other reason than having unlimited capacity for conversions. Thus far, they do no see fit to add this change to their roadmap.

Comment: [cont'd] With more than 14,000 products, each having from 1 to a dozen or so conversions, it is proving a daunting task to get all values in-line within a single record. Frustrating.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I'm reviewing your answer to the previous question you linked. In it, you have the following snippet:  

'WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@MaxTally) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --100 rows, add more Ns for more rows'  

Does "N N1, N N2" in that snippet *already* provide for 100 resulting rows, or would I need to add "N N3, N N4, ... N N99, N N100" to have enough for 100 values?

Comment: `N N1, N N2` is creating 100 rows. Adding another cross join to `N` would result in 1,000 rows. Another 10,000. You get the idea. :)