# single column value in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ID|Class | Number
--+------+---------
1 | 1    |  58.2
2 | 1    |  85.4
3 | 2    |  28.2
4 | 2    |  55.4
```

The desired result would be:

```
Column1 |Number | Column2 | Number
--------+-------+---------+---------
1       | 58.2  | 2       |28.2
1       | 85.4  | 2       |55.4
```

What would be the required SQL?

Comment: How do you decide how to combine rows?

Comment: This *looks* like conditional aggregation on a `ROW_NUMBER` Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63521138/2029983)

Answer (score 0):

You can user `row_number()` and aggregate:

```
select 1, max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then number end),
       2, max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then number end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by class order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by ceiling(seqnum / 2.0);
```

The aggregation uses arithmetic to put pairs of rows for each class into one row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 1 AS Column1,t2.Number,2 AS Column2,t1.Number
FROM
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM test11
   ) t2

   INNER JOIN

   (
   SELECT *
   FROM test11
   ) t1
   ON t1.Class = t2.Class
WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
```

Demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36d5a53d39d2caa5d3a20ece4080113f)