# Join 2 tables - Multiple FK to one PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table with header data and a second table with measurement data. They look like this:

```
Table1                            Table2 

| headID   |   date   |           | headID   |   data1  |   data2  | 
|----------|----------|           |----------|----------|----------| 
| 1        | 08.10.21 |           | 1        |   'abc'  |  'xyz'   |
| 2        | 09.10.21 |           | 1        |   '123'  |  '999'   |
| 3        | 14.10.21 |           | 1        |   '456'  |  '888'   |
                                  | 2        |   '222'  |  '000'   |
                                  | 3        |   '111'  |  '333'   |
```

Is it possible to join both tables and put every entry from Table2 into one row?

Like this:

```
HeadID, date, data1, data2, data1, data2, data1, data2
1, 08.10.21, 'abc', 'xyz', '123', '999', '456', '888'
```

Comment: Only tag the DBMS you really use. MySQL and SQL Server are very different.

Comment: You *could* do this, but what would you expect if there are only 2 rows, 4 columns? If there were 10 rows then 20 columns? For such a scent you would need dynamic SQL, and I would advise against that. Why not retain the data in it's normalised design?

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Assume it can be done (which is not sure), what would you do with a variable number of columns, since `Table2` can contain any rows for `headID` value 1. Not to mention how would you name them, column aliases need to be unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

you could just use select to get details of each record.

```
select t1.HeadID, t1.date, t2.data1, t2.data2 from Table1 t1,Table2 t2 where t1.HeadID=t2.HeadID;
```

which should return all records of table2 along with table1 details.

or use right join

```
select t1.*,t2.date1,t2.date2 from Table_1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.HeadID=t2.HeadID;
```

Comment: It's 2021; why are you still using that 80's join syntax? It was superceded some 29 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- POSSIBLE SOLUTION FOR MS SQLSEVER -- THIS IS A VERY LIMITED DATA SET...DOES YOU SAMPLE COVER ALL POSSIBILITIES  ??
-- PLEASE POST SET UP SCRIPT FOR DATA....YOU WILL GET BETTER AND MORE ACCURATE RESPONSE  

USE [tempdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
  [headId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [date] [date] NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
  [headId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [data1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [data2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([headId], [date]) VALUES(1, CAST(N'2021-10-08' AS date))
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([headId], [date]) VALUES(2, CAST(N'2021-10-09' AS date))
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([headId], [date]) VALUES(3, CAST(N'2021-10-14' AS date))

INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([headId], [data1], [data2]) VALUES(1, N'abc', N'xyz')
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([headId], [data1], [data2]) VALUES(1, N'123', N'999')
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([headId], [data1], [data2]) VALUES(1, N'456', N'888')
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([headId], [data1], [data2]) VALUES(2, N'222', N'000')
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([headId], [data1], [data2]) VALUES(3, N'111', N'333');

--  MAYBE A SOLUTION (ms sql )

WITH c
AS (SELECT
    headId,
    STRING_AGG(data1 + ', ' + data2, ', ') AS datarow
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY headID)

SELECT
  t.headId,
  t.date,
  c.datarow
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN c
  ON t.headId = c.headId

  DROP TABLE Table1
  DROP TABLE Table2
```