# SQL transpose multiple rows to different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have SQL server data Table, like this:

| ID | SYMPTOM1 | SYMPTOM2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 1 | C | D |
| 2 | E | F |
| 3 | A | C |
| 3 | D | E |

I'd like to obtain this:

| ID | SYMPTOM1 | SYMPTOM2 | SYMPTOM3 | SYMPTOM4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D |
| 2 | E | F |  |  |
| 3 | A | C | D | E |

That should be an "easy" pivot, but I can't figure it out.
How could a SQL query be written?

***EDIT**

Excuse me, I have neglected an important detail. The number of rows in the table is very large, some 500.000 so the IDs are very large.

Comment: Do you want it as a pivot-by-using-tsql-PIVOT or a pivot-by-conditional aggregation? (i.e. a sqlserver specific solution or an SQL general one). Is the order of syptom expression important?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as a self join - use row number to have another column that is either 1 or 2 (depending on how many times ID appeared), 1 should always appear, 2 sometimes appears, so left joining those rows with 2 onto those rows with 1 (based on the id) gives you the end result..

```
WITH x AS(
  SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.SYMPTOM1,
    t.SYMPTOM2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.SYMPTOM1) as rn
  FROM t
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  x x1
  LEFT JOIN x x2 ON x1.id = x2.id AND x1.rn = 1 AND x2.rn = 2
```

Comment: Sounds inefficient

Comment: Measure, don't guess

Comment: @spiderman typo, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot on a row-number

```sql
SELECT
  t.ID,
  SYMPTOM1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.SYMPTOM1 END),
  SYMPTOM2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.SYMPTOM2 END),
  SYMPTOM3 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.SYMPTOM1 END),
  SYMPTOM4 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.SYMPTOM2 END)
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.*,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Comment: There's actually no need to unpivot here. Just have 2 conditional aggregates on each value of `RN`; 1 for `Symptom1` and the other for `Symptom2`.

Comment: Quite right, thanks