# Dynamic pivot table query with grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out a query for a pivot, but grouping by a column first.
I have the following data in my table:

| ID | Label | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag3 | Tag4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | B1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | C1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | A1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | B1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | C1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The final result I'm looking for is something like this:

| ID | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 (1,0,0,1) |  |
| 2 | B1 (0,0,1,0) | C1 (0,1,0,0) |
| 3 | A1 (1,1,0,0) |  |
| 4 | B1 (0,0,0,1) | C1 (1,0,0,1) |

In this example I have 2 columns max, but it could be N columns.
I worked with pivots before, but this one adds an extra difficulty with the Tag columns in there.

Comment: I really recommend against this. Both your current design, and the new break basic normalisation principles (the latter even more so). Just normalise your data.

Comment: Is the number of `Tag` columns also variable, then? Otherwise it's a fairly straightforward application of existing techniques, after making a new column that concatenates the label and tags and pivoting that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, the tag columns is always 4

Comment: It'll still need to be dynamic, @JeroenMostert , the OP said that there could be more than 2 rows for a individual value of `ID` (and i assume they don't know *how many* rows there could be).

Comment: @Larnu: yes, but then at least it's a "normal" dynamic pivot, insofar as those things can be called normal, with hopefully plenty of questions dealing with the technique (although of course I'm too lazy to search for them now).

Comment: In the words of Blue Peter, @JeroenMostert: "Here's one I made earlier." [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, it seems you are looking for some Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select ID
              ,Item = row_number() over (partition by ID order by Label)
              ,Value = concat(Label,'' ('',Tag1,'','',Tag2,'','',Tag3,'','',Tag4,'')'')
         From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in ( ' + stuff(( Select distinct ','+quotename(row_number() over (partition by ID order by Label)) 
                                              From  YourTable
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'') +')) pvt
'

Exec(@SQL)


Results
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.