# SQL question using PIVOT, no aggregation column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I would like to do a `PIVOT` on my table but I don't have aggregation column.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, DataHora) AS dia,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DataHora, 108) AS hora
FROM 
    [clientes].[dbo].[Tb_Ponto]
```

Result:

```
2021-12-27  12:41
2021-12-28  12:42
2021-12-28  13:03
2021-12-28  14:08
```

I would like it to stay like this:

```
2021-12-27  12:41 |  NULL | NULL 
2021-12-28  12:42 | 13:03 | 14:08
```

Comment: Pivoting is a type of aggregation. You need to pivot on the `ROW_NUMBER` and use `MAX`. Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: `CONVERT(time, DataHora) AS hora` might be more sensible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the window function `row_number() over()` to your query, then it becomes a small matter to pivot.

This assumes you have a know or maximum number of columns.

```
Select *
 From (
        SELECT dia   = CONVERT(date, DataHora)
              ,hora  = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataHora,108)
              ,ColNr = row_number() over (partition by CONVERT(date, DataHora) order by DataHora)
          FROM [clientes].[dbo].[Tb_Ponto]
      ) src
 Pivot ( max(hora) for ColNr in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) pvt
```

Comment: exactly that , thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As your data is ordered by date and time, you can group it by date, add sequence numbers to rows in each group, and then perform a row-to-column transposition. If you use SQL pivot(… in(column_list)), you should specify column_list. The value can be fixed in a simple scenario. When there are many columns or the number of columns is indefinite, you need to write a stored procedure to dynamically generate the columns. The process is complicated. An alternative is to move data out of database and process it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easy to be integrated into a Java program and generate simple code. It can do this with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =MSSQL.query("SELECT CONVERT(date, DataHora) AS dia,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DataHora, 108)AS hora FROM [clientes].[dbo].[Tb_Ponto] ORDER BY 1,2") |
| 2 | =A1.derive("hora"/ranki(#2;#1):fn).pivot(#1;#3,#2) |