# Combining two SQL tables with common ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I want to combine into one. They have LinkID as a common ID, but I can't figure out how to query to combine them to appear on one line instead of multiple.

Address Table

| LinkID | Address1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 Homeless Street |
| 2 | 115 N Turner Drive |
| 3 | 1213 Riverside Avenue |
| 4 | 2015 Shorewood Drive |

Contact Table

| LinkID | Contact_c | Relation_c | Enddate_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ARNOLD COLLINS | FATHER | NULL |
| 1 | PAMELA COLLINS | MOTHER | NULL |
| 2 | LUCY HOWARD | MOTHER | NULL |
| 2 | LEROY SHEPHARD | NEIGH | 2/1/22 |
| 3 | ROGER RUSELL | FATHER | NULL |
| 3 | AMY RUSELL | MOTHER | NULL |
| 4 | JACKIE BARD | MOTHER | NULL |
| 4 | JASON BIEL | FRIEND | NULL |

Where Enddate_d is NULL

Desired Results

| LinkID | Contact1 | Relation1 | Contact2 | Relation2 | Address1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ARNOLD COLLINS | FATHER | PAMELA COLLINS | MOTHER | 1234 Homeless Street |
| 2 | LUCY HOWARD | MOTHER | NULL | NULL | 115 N Turner Drive |
| 3 | ROGER RUSELL | FATHER | AMY RUSELL | MOTHER | 1213 Riverside Avenue |
| 4 | JACKIE BARD | MOTHER | JASON BIEL | FRIEND | 2015 Shorewood Drive |

Comment: is there a a maximum contact per address?  so if 10 people lived at 1 address you'd have 20 columns? 1 contact 1 relation (2*10)?  if no limit this becomes a dynamic pivot and is better suited for managing in a report or UI, not the SQL directly.

Comment: What defines a contact as 1 or 2 (or 3...)?

Comment: Converting rows to columns is called a "pivot". There are many examples you can find by searching. But you need to consider the first comment to know which approach will be needed.

Comment: There are, however, plenty of examples of how to achieve a pivot with row numbering, including dynamic ones (I know have one such [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)).

Comment: There could be a large amount of contact entries per ID. I will research SQL PIVOTING and ask questions if needed.

Comment: Sounds like you need a dynamic pivot based on the row number then, not just "basic" pivoting. The link answer above does demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER...` function can be used to assign sequence numbers to the contacts, and conditional aggregates of the form `MAX(CASE ...)` can be used to build up a pivoted result.

```
DECLARE @Address TABLE(LinkID INT, Address1 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Address
VALUES
    (1, '1234 Homeless Street'),
    (2, '115 N Turner Drive'),
    (3, '1213 Riverside Avenue'),
    (4, '2015 Shorewood Drive')

DECLARE @Contact TABLE(LinkID INT, Contact_c VARCHAR(100), Relation_c VARCHAR(100), Enddate_d DATE)
INSERT @Contact
VALUES
    (1, 'ARNOLD COLLINS', 'FATHER', NULL),
    (1, 'PAMELA COLLINS', 'MOTHER', NULL),
    (2, 'LUCY HOWARD', 'MOTHER', NULL),
    (2, 'LEROY SHEPHARD', 'NEIGH', '2022-01-01'),
    (3, 'ROGER RUSELL', 'FATHER', NULL),
    (3, 'AMY RUSELL', 'MOTHER', NULL),
    (4, 'JACKIE BARD', 'MOTHER', NULL),
    (4, 'JASON BIEL', 'FRIEND', NULL)
;
WITH Contacts_CTE AS (
    SELECT *, Ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LinkID ORDER BY Relation_c)
    FROM @Contact
    WHERE Enddate_d IS NULL
)
SELECT
    A.LinkID,
    Contact1  = MAX(CASE WHEN C.Ordinal = 1 THEN C.Contact_c END),
    Relation1 = MAX(CASE WHEN C.Ordinal = 1 THEN C.Relation_c END),
    Contact2  = MAX(CASE WHEN C.Ordinal = 2 THEN C.Contact_c END),
    Relation2 = MAX(CASE WHEN C.Ordinal = 2 THEN C.Relation_c END),
    A.Address1
FROM @Address A
LEFT JOIN Contacts_CTE C ON C.LinkID = A.LinkID
GROUP BY A.LinkID, A.Address1
ORDER BY A.LinkID
```

The PIVOT clause could be used, but it has limitations which make performing pivots on multiple values somewhat awkward.

Results:

| LinkID | Contact1 | Relation1 | Contact2 | Relation2 | Address1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ARNOLD COLLINS | FATHER | PAMELA COLLINS | MOTHER | 1234 Homeless Street |
| 2 | LUCY HOWARD | MOTHER | LEROY SHEPHARD | null | null |
| 3 | ROGER RUSELL | FATHER | AMY RUSELL | MOTHER | 1213 Riverside Avenue |
| 4 | JASON BIEL | FRIEND | JACKIE BARD | MOTHER | 2015 Shorewood Drive |

The order is different from your results due to the `ORDER BY` used with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. That order can be adjusted as needed.

See [this db<>fifddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=251932779e75fa241d5aca72a6a81419) for a demo.