# How do I transpose/merge multiple rows in to a single row in SQL while generating pseudo column headers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I get this data:

| ItemID | LocID |
| --- | --- |
| 85474 | ABAB |
| 85474 | ABBB |
| 85474 | ABCB |
| 85474 | ABDB |
| 85474 | ABAB |
| 85474 | ABCB |
| 85474 | ABEB |

To look like this:

| ItemID | LocID_1 | LocID_2 | LocID_3 | LocID_4 | LocID_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85474 | ABAB | ABBB | ABCB | ABDB | ABEB |

Sometimes LocID will repeat. There should be no repeats in the row. Sometimes there will be 10 different locations so LocID_***n*** should grow or be capped at 10.

I've been looking into pivoting but I don't want values to turn into headers. I need new headers/pseudo headers to fill the row.

UPDATE:

Removed images.

UPDATE:

Turns out there is a solution here: [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

However, there are duplicate values in the merged rows. LocID's should not have any dupes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data or results is the fastest way I've seen here to have your question downvoted and ignored.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Solid advise.