# Add columns to a set of results depending how many rows found

Tags: sql-server

I don't have sample datathat fits the example below, and it's more a theoretical question rather than a data-driven one...

I have a table called CustomerOrders. A query looks to see if any customers haven't ordered anything for more than 4 days (again, it's just an example but easier than explaining the real purpose).

If there are such customers, then the query searches an Communications table that records whether or not sales staff have noted that it's been four days or more since an order was received from that customer, and what action they're taking to address this.

Depending on the number of days since the last order, and the number of times sales staff have logged their acknowledgement (ideally it should be every day until they place an order), each customer appears in the results like this:

```
FirstName, LastName, LastOrderDate, NumDaysSince, SalesStaffCommentDate, SalesComment
```

At present, each entry sales staff log a comment about this date gap appears as a separate row in this result set, each essentially repeating themselves, other than the last two columns.

What I would prefer is for this result set to be set out as:

```
FirstName, LastName, LastOrderDate, NumDaysSince, SalesStaffCommentDate[1], SalesComment[1], SalesStaffCommentDate[2], SalesComment[2]
```

etc, with the number of additional comment and date columns showing the comments made, but all on one row.

But if the sales team only logged two comments on one customer, but ten comments on another, there is obviously a disparity between the number of columns that could be filled.

Is it possible to display the data in this way?

EDIT - thanks to @Larnu and @Smor so far.

To try and give a bit more data. This is how my data looks:

```
NAME       LASTORDERDATE   NUMDAYSSINCE  SALESSTAFFCOMMENTDATE  SALESCOMMENT
John Smith 2022-06-12      5             2022-06-15             Tried to call
John Smith 2022-06-12      5             2022-06-16             Call back later
John Smith 2022-06-12      5             2022-06-17             Not required
```

I want it to look like this:

```
John Smith 2022-06-12  5   2022-06-15  Tried to call   2022-06-16  Call back later  2022-06-17  Not required.
```

There may be anything from 1 - 10 entries before the customer orders again and reset the counter back to being < 4 days since their last.

@larnu, are you saying that the link you give allows me to present the data in this way? Ordinarily I would export this data to PBI and pivot it to display as I need it to, but for this bit of data I'm unable to do that, and so it needs to be in SQL.

Hope that clarifies things in case I was being a bit too vague.

Comment: This is pivoting, but on the `ROW_NUMBER`; if you don't know how many rows you'll have (and it's not got an upper limit) you'll need to use dynamic SQL. I demonstrate how to achieve both in this question: [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns) Ideally, though this would be something for your presentation layer.

Comment: Think carefully about how you intend to consume or present this information and what technology you will use to do so. The query might be the least of your problems.

Comment: Sorry, just in case the edit doesn't trigger a notification, I've added a little more context.