# Separate different types of values from the same column into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one column that contains different ways of calling each USER (email, phone), there is a separate line for each way of calling. I want to consolidate the information, which will be presented to me in the same line mail, phone of the USER. How can I write this in a query?
for example:

from:

```
ID  USER    communication       
1   boy 50000148        
2   boy 5405112741      
3   boy boy@gmail.com
```

To:

```
ID USER EMAIL         PHONE1    PHONE2
1 boy boy@gmail.com 506770148 542212741
```

Comment: Honestly, get a human being to do this; you have nothing to denote what type of information that is. Though I suggest against "phone1" "phone2" etc; if a person needs many phone numbers use a separate table, or distinguish what they are: HomePhone, MobilePhone, WorkPhone.

Comment: @Larnu It does not matter to me so much that it will be excellent "phone", "Email". For me it can also be "Communicaton1", "Communicaton2" ... I just need the lead list arranged by USER without duplicates

Comment: If it's just a "communication" channel, what you have is the "better" solution, as at least it's normalised. Though I show how to pivot such data statically and dynamically in this question: [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Answer (score -4):

1. it's a example of converting rows to columns and data should have phone1,phone2 and email as row name in column communication.
   Use case when and convert rows to column(pivot as per the result image you posted)

[Point 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTX1t.png)

```
select user,id,
sum(case when communication='phone1'
    then value end) as phone1,
sum(case when communication='phone2'
    then value end) as phone2,
 max( case when communication='email'
    then value end )as email    
from test
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIOcx.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could add a code example?

Comment: @Yashir I have added code, hope it helps you