# SQL2017 TSQL Pivot multiple rows to flattenend table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, sql-server-2017

I am trying to "flatten" a delivery schedule table from many rows for one customer into one row per customer.  Each customer can have from 1 to 7 LeadDays, OrderDays, and DeliveryDays.

This is what I have to work with:

```
CustomerNumber | Company | Year | WeekNumber | OrderDate  | OrderDayName | LeadDays | DeliveryDate | DeliveryDayName
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-03 |  Sunday      |   1.0    |  2022-04-04  | Monday
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-04 |  Monday      |   1.0    |  2022-04-05  | Tuesday
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-05 |  Tuesday     |   1.0    |  2022-04-06  | Wednesday
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-06 |  Wednesday   |   1.0    |  2022-04-07  | Thursday
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-07 |  Thursday    |   1.0    |  2022-04-08  | Friday
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-08 |  Friday      |   1.0    |  2022-04-09  | Saturday
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |  2022-04-09 |  Saturday    |   1.0    |  2022-04-10  | Sunday
310365         | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-05 |  Tuesday     |   1.0    |  2022-04-06  | Wednesday
310365         | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-07 |  Thursday    |   1.0    |  2022-04-08  | Friday
310428         | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-06 |  Wednesday   |   1.0    |  2022-04-07  | Thursday
19401          | Comp_B  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-04 |  Monday      |   1.0    |  2022-04-05  | Tuesday
19401          | Comp_B  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-05 |  Tuesday     |   1.0    |  2022-04-06  | Wednesday
19401          | Comp_B  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-06 |  Wednesday   |   1.0    |  2022-04-07  | Thursday
19401          | Comp_B  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-07 |  Thursday    |   1.0    |  2022-04-08  | Friday
19401          | Comp_B  | 2022 |     15     | 2022-04-08 |  Friday      |   1.0    |  2022-04-09  | Saturday
```

.....and this is what I need it to look like:

```
CustomerNumber | Company | Year | WeekNumber | LeadDays_1 | OrderDate_1 | DeliveryDate_1 | LeadDays_2 | OrderDate_2 | DeliveryDate_2 | LeadDays_3 | OrderDate_3 | DeliveryDate_3 | LeadDays_4 | OrderDate_4 | DeliveryDate_4 | LeadDays_5 | OrderDate_5 | DeliveryDate_5 | LeadDays_6 | OrderDate_6 | DeliveryDate_6 | LeadDays_7 | OrderDate_7 | DeliveryDate_7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5002           | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |   1.0      | 2022-04-03  | 2022-04-04     |   1.0      | 2022-04-04  | 2022-04-05     |   1.0      | 2022-04-05  | 2022-04-06     |   1.0      | 2022-04-06  | 2022-04-07     |   1.0      | 2022-04-07  | 2022-04-08     |   1.0      | 2022-04-08  | 2022-04-09     |   1.0      | 2022-04-09  | 2022-04-10
310365         | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |   1.0      | 2022-04-05  | 2022-04-06     |   1.0      | 2022-04-07  | 2022-04-08     |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |  
310428         | Comp_A  | 2022 |     15     |   1.0      | 2022-04-06  | 2022-04-07     |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |                |            |             |  
19401          | Comp_B  | 2022 |     15     |   1.0      | 2022-04-04  | 2022-04-05     |   1.0      | 2022-04-05  | 2022-04-06     |   1.0      | 2022-04-06  | 2022-04-07     |   1.0      | 2022-04-07  | 2022-04-08     |   1.0      | 2022-04-08  | 2022-04-09     |            |             |                |            |             |
```

I know it should be a (relatively simple?) PIVOT table, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: @Charlieface, I can see where it might, but I think I'm just having a brain-fart moment and am not able to apply it to my situation.

Comment: @Charlieface: to clarify, using that example link, I'm going to need an "N set" for each of my columns (LeadDays_S, OrderDate_X, and DeliveryDate_X)?

Comment: Do you know what is the maximum possible number of N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation using `MAX(CASE` which is much more flexible than `PIVOT`. In your case, you first need to generate a row-number to pivot over

```sql
SELECT
  CustomerNumber,
  Company,
  Year,
  WeekNumber,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN LeadDays     END)     LeadDays_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN OrderDate    END)    OrderDate_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN DeliveryDate END) DeliveryDate_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN LeadDays     END)     LeadDays_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN OrderDate    END)    OrderDate_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN DeliveryDate END) DeliveryDate_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN LeadDays     END)     LeadDays_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN OrderDate    END)    OrderDate_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN DeliveryDate END) DeliveryDate_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN LeadDays     END)     LeadDays_4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN OrderDate    END)    OrderDate_4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN DeliveryDate END) DeliveryDate_4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN LeadDays     END)     LeadDays_5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN OrderDate    END)    OrderDate_5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN DeliveryDate END) DeliveryDate_6
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY CustomerNumber, Company, Year, WeekNumber
          ORDER BY OrderDate, DeliveryDate)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  CustomerNumber,
  Company,
  Year,
  WeekNumber;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4da76f5e44547906385fd13ca35bf0a1)

Comment: Thank you!  This is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice CrossTab, @charlieface