# Split multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 Columns:

```
SELECT
ID ,Project
FROM projects
```

The table shows me the projects in which the Employee(ID) is working in:

```
ID | Project
--------------
ID1| Project1
ID1| Project2
ID1| Project3
ID1| Project4
ID2| Project1
ID2| Project2
ID3| Project1
ID3| Project2
ID3| Project3
```

In case when one employee is working in more than 1 project, i need to split the different projects into different columns named . The result should be looking like this:

```
ID |   Col1   |   Col2   |   Col3   |   Col4   |   Col5  |
----------------------------------------------------------
ID1| Project1 | Project2 | Project3 | Project4 |   NULL  |
ID2| Project1 | Project2 |   NULL   |   NULL   |   NULL  |
ID3| Project1 | Project2 | Project3 |   NULL   |   NULL  |
```

Since there are never more than 5 projects, the number of the columns can be fixed at 5.

I tried with different `row_number()` and pivot approaches but failed due to my inexperience.

Comment: *"I tried with different row_number() and pivot approaches but failed due to my inexperience."* and what were those attempts? You forgot to include them in your question. Does this answer your question?[Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Project) rn
    FROM projects
)

SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Project END) AS Col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Project END) AS Col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Project END) AS Col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Project END) AS Col4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Project END) AS Col5
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

If there be some other column which should determine the ordering of projects for each `ID`, then update the call to `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I tried Row_Number as R and pivot(max(project) for R IN(.............) as PivotTable but that didn't work for me. I also tried a XML approach i found online but this only worked if i had put existing results from the different rows as columns. Your approach is perfect and exactly what i need. Thanks!