# How to pivot wider in SQL or use a more "dynamic" form of the LEAD function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks as follows:

```
Policy Number Benefit Code Transaction Code
1             A            2
1             B            1
2             A            3
3             A            2
1             C            2
```

For analysis purposes, it would be much more convenient to have the table in the following form:

```
PN BC 1 TC 1 BC 2 TC 2 BC 3 TC 3
1  A    2    B    1    C    2
2  A    3    NULL NULL NULL NULL
3  A    2    NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

I believe this can be done, for example, in R using the `tidyverse` package, where the concept is basically pivoting the table from long-form to wide-form. Now, I know that I could possibly use the `LEAD` function in SQL, but the problem/issue is that I do not know how many benefit codes and transaction codes each policy has (i.e. they are not fixed).

Thus, my query is:

1. How can I "pivot wider" my table to achieve something like the above?
2. Other than "pivoting wider", is there a more dynamic form of the `LEAD` function in SQL, where it takes all subsequent rows of a group (in my case, each policy number) and puts them in new columns?

Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns)

Comment: @Larnu Yes, it kinda does! However, may I know what "dynamic SQL" is? Is that a totally different SQL that I need to download? I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17, if that matters!

Comment: Dynamic SQL is SQL that is created dynamically. It's not a different dialect, and what IDE (like) application you are using doesn't change that.

Comment: If you have a defined maximum number you could do that many self-left joins. This would cause any rows with less to return NULL, but it seems that's what you want in that instance anyway. This would also require that you have some sort of row identifier added too, but that should be as simple as a CTE which added a ROW_NUMBER partitioned by Policy Number and ordered however you need.