# Dynamic SQL Code for Transposing Mulitple Order Rows Into Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and looking for an easy way to dynamically pivot these rows for an unknown number of columns, in this case orders.

This is my example data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#order') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #order;

CREATE TABLE #order (row INT, customer_no INT, name VARCHAR(500), salutation VARCHAR(500), email VARCHAR(500), order_no INT, order_dt DATETIME, attend_dt DATETIME, time_slot VARCHAR(8), num_tickets INT)
INSERT INTO #order VALUES
    (1, 246501, 'John Smith', 'Mr. Smith', 'email@email.org', 8675309, '2023-05-04 14:22:32.407', '2023-05-21 10:00:00.000', '11:30 AM', 2)
,   (2, 246501, 'John Smith', 'Mr. Smith', 'email@email.org', 8675310, '2023-05-05 12:22:32.407', '2023-05-21 10:00:00.000', '1:30 PM', 2)
,   (3, 246501, 'John Smith', 'Mr. Smith', 'email@email.org', 8675311, '2023-05-06 15:22:32.407', '2023-05-21 10:00:00.000', '3:30 PM', 2)
;
```

And this is the result I'm looking for:

| customer_no | name | salautation | email | order_no_ 1 | order_dt_1 | attend_dt_1 | time_slot_1 | num_tickets_1 | order_no_2 | order_dt_2 | attend_dt_2 | time_slot_2 | num_tickets_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 246501 | John Smith | Mr. Smith | email@email.org | 8675309 | 2023-05-04 14:22:32.407 | 2023-05-21 10:00:00.000 | 11:30 AM | 2 | 8675310 | 2023-05-05 12:22:32.407 | 2023-05-21 10:00:00.000 | 1:30 PM | 2 |

I've tried to write the dynamic query but the result only includes the order_no and not the details. What am I missing to include the other columns?

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
,       @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +  + QUOTENAME(row)
from #order
group by row
order by row
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
,1,1,'')

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +  + QUOTENAME(row) 
                            from #order
                            group by row
                            order by row
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT customer_no,' +  @cols + ' into #orders from 
            (
            select customer_no, row, order_no
            from #order
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(order_no)
            for row in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p; SELECT * 
             FROM #order p
             LEFT OUTER JOIN #orders o ON p.customer_no = o.customer_no'

EXECUTE (@query);

DROP TABLE #order
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 15.0.4198.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution to your problem:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#order') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #order;

CREATE TABLE #order (row INT, customer_no INT, name VARCHAR(500), salutation VARCHAR(500), email VARCHAR(500), order_no INT, order_dt DATETIME, attend_dt DATETIME, time_slot VARCHAR(8), num_tickets INT)
INSERT INTO #order VALUES
    (1, 246501, 'John Smith', 'Mr. Smith', 'email@email.org', 8675309, '2023-05-04 14:22:32.407', '2023-05-21 10:00:00.000', '11:30 AM', 2)
,   (2, 246501, 'John Smith', 'Mr. Smith', 'email@email.org', 8675310, '2023-05-05 12:22:32.407', '2023-05-21 10:00:00.000', '1:30 PM', 2)
,   (3, 246501, 'John Smith', 'Mr. Smith', 'email@email.org', 8675311, '2023-05-06 15:22:32.407', '2023-05-21 10:00:00.000', '3:30 PM', 2)
;

DECLARE @row_id int = (SELECT   MAX(row) FROM   #order)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    select customer_no, name, salutation, email'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  TOP(@row_id) row_number() OVER(ORDER BY @@spid) AS rows
    FROM    sys.objects so
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects so2
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns so3
    )
SELECT  @sql = @sql + (
    SELECT  ',  max(case when row = ' + rowsN + ' then order_no end) order_no_' + rowsN + N'
        ,   max(case when row = ' + rowsN + ' then convert(varchar(30), order_dt, 121) end) order_dt_' + rowsN + N'
        ,   max(case when row = ' + rowsN + ' then convert(varchar(30), attend_dt, 121) end) attend_dt_' + rowsN + N'
        ,   max(case when row = ' + rowsN + ' then time_slot end) time_slot_' + rowsN + N'
        ,   max(case when row = ' + rowsN + ' then num_tickets end) num_tickets_' + rowsN
    FROM    cte c
    CROSS apply (
        SELECT  cast(rows AS nvarchar(max)) AS rowsN
        ) r
    ORDER BY c.rows
    FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
SELECT  @sql = @sql + N'
from #order
group by customer_no, name, salutation, email'

EXEC(@sql)
```

I use manual pivot in the dynamic sql because auto pivot is usually not flexible enough.

You can use newer stuff like STRING_AGG and GENERATE_SERIES instead of the old XML PATH and sys.objects range but this should work too.

Comment: Thanks D-FENS, I mean, @siggemannen. This was really helpful. Seeing this, I feel really silly for not being able to solve this. Very clever.