# Transpose data for a fixed number of rows, supplying defaults where data doesn't exist?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transpose

I have a table that stores version information on particular accounts. Below is the structure and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Account 
(
    [Account No] int,
    [User] varchar(50),
    [Version No] tinyint,
    [Version Comment] varchar(280),
    [Date] datetime2(2)
)

INSERT INTO #Account
VALUES (1, 'Admin', 1, 'New Account', '2024-03-01 12:00:00.00'),
       (1, 'User', 2, 'Edit Account - Add name', '2024-03-02 8:00:00.00'),
       (1, 'Admin', 3, 'Edit Account - Fix name', '2024-03-02 11:00:00.00'),
       (2, 'Admin', 1, 'New Account', '2024-03-02 14:00:00.00'),
       (3, 'User', 1, 'New Account', '2024-03-03 8:00:00.00'),
       (3, 'Admin', 2, 'Edit Account - Add website url', '2024-03-03 12:00:00.00')
```

I need to transpose that data to look like this (using Account No. 3 as an example):

| Username1 | Username2 | ... | Username20 | Title1 | Title2 | ... | Title20 | Comment1 | Comment2 | ... | Comment20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User | Admin | ... | Some Default Value | Version #1 - 3/3/2024 8:00 AM | Version #2 - 3/3/2024 12:00 PM | ... | Some Default Value | New Account | Edit Account | ... | Some Default Value |

In other words, for a particular account number, I need to...

1. Use data from the table where a version exists and supply a default value where it doesn't, for 20 versions (it will always be 20 versions)
2. Transpose this data, appending the version number to the column name.

Ideally, I understand that this data transformation would be done by the front-end system of the database, but in this case I need SQL to do it.

I tried this originally:

```
DECLARE @AccountNo int = 3

-- Get the name of the users that have created each version
SELECT CONCAT('Username', [Version No]) 'Name',
        [User] 'Value'
FROM #Account
WHERE [Account No] = @AccountNo

UNION ALL

-- Get the title of each version
SELECT CONCAT('Title', [Version No]) 'Name',
        CONCAT('Version #', [Version No], ' - ', FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime2(2), [Date] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')) 'Value'
FROM #Account
WHERE [Account No] = @AccountNo

UNION ALL

-- Get the comment left for each version
SELECT CONCAT('Comment', [Version No]) 'Name',
        [Version Comment] 'Value'
FROM #Account
WHERE [Account No] = @AccountNo
```

But this doesn't supply me the default values and it requires the data to be transposed. I've also looked at other options (or combination of options), such as...

- PIVOT/UNPIVOT
- SQL sequences w/ some kind of join (to fill in the remaining values up to 20)
- CASE expressions
- Multiple IF statements

...but I have yet to create something that works, much less is performant. Thoughts?

EDIT:

- I am using SQL Server 2022
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-multiple-rows-into-one-row-multiple-columns) is a helpful similar question, per the comments.

Comment: This type of query is known as a crosstab and really should be left to the presentation layer. Do you always want 20 per group? If so, this is a little bit easier but if the number of column groups is dynamic it becomes a lot more complicated.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, it will always be 20

Comment: Can you do this in the presentation layer instead? Also, I would urge you to not put spaces in your column names. Also, don't use reserved words as column names. Usually reserved words are too ambiguous anyway. Consider the column `DATE`. What is that? Date created? Date Edited? Some other date entirely?

Comment: @SeanLange Due to different particularities of the presentation layer, I’m looking for a way to do this in SQL. Thank you for the other suggestions. Regarding the “Date” column, in my database table that is actually “Valid From” as this is a system-versioned table, but that seemed like an unnecessary complication to include in the question.

Comment: That makes sense. I would still avoid spaces as it forces you to constantly wrap column names in square brackets. :D

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, thank you! The switch to removing spaces in column names is definitely a change that may need to be made soon:)

Comment: I'm not sure what's tripping you up, for default values you can use `ISNULL(<some expression>, 'SomeDefault')`. Also, why do you need to do this in SQL, the final result is impossible to work with any further

Comment: @siggemannen Upon a second look of the other question, you are correct. I have updated my question accordingly. Thank you! Regarding your other comment, I need the data in this format for the presentation layer, so I am creating a SP to do this as SQL is generally better suited for manipulating data than the front-end software I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do this in the presentation layer instead of the database. But sometimes that isn't possible. In this case, because the number of column groups is always going to be the same you can use conditional aggregation. I have no idea what your output column named "Title" is from the sample data so I will let you sort that out. I demonstrated the first 5 columns in a group so you can see the technique. I will let you copy and paste for all 20 repeating groups.

Also, not sure which version of sql server you are using so I assumed 2022. The generate_series function is not available in earlier versions. I just used to generate a table with numbers 1 - 20 easily. There are lots of other ways to tackle that part.

```
with SortedVals as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [Account No] order by [Date])
    from #Account
)
select sv.[Account No]
    , UserName1 = max(case when x.value = 1 then sv.[User] end)
    , UserName2 = max(case when x.value = 2 then sv.[User] end)
    , UserName3 = max(case when x.value = 3 then sv.[User] end)
    , UserName4 = max(case when x.value = 4 then sv.[User] end)
    , UserName5 = max(case when x.value = 5 then sv.[User] end)
    , Comment1 = max(case when x.value = 1 then sv.[Version Comment] end)
    , Comment2 = max(case when x.value = 2 then sv.[Version Comment] end)
    , Comment3 = max(case when x.value = 3 then sv.[Version Comment] end)
    , Comment4 = max(case when x.value = 4 then sv.[Version Comment] end)
    , Comment5 = max(case when x.value = 5 then sv.[Version Comment] end)
from generate_series(1, 20, 1) x
left join SortedVals sv on sv.RowNum = x.value
where sv.[Account No] is not null
group by sv.[Account No]
```

Comment: Thank you! Both answers provide excellent solutions. Only checking this as the solution because I personally find it a bit more readable. However, upon a quick test, it appears that all three solutions (including the associated question) have a similar query cost in the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the purpose of such a 60-column table is unclear. However, as a task it is interesting.
I will present a 4-column option that is easily and understandably expandable to the desired number of columns.

1.Unpivot with CROSS APPLY

| AccountNo | UserName | VersionNo | VersionComment | rn | AtrName | AtrValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | 1 | New Account | 1 | UserName1 | Admin |
| 1 | Admin | 1 | New Account | 1 | VersionNo1 | 1 |
| 1 | Admin | 1 | New Account | 1 | VersionComment1 | New Account |
| 1 | User | 2 | Edit Account - Add name | 2 | UserName2 | User |
| 1 | User | 2 | Edit Account - Add name | 2 | VersionNo2 | 2 |
| 1 | User | 2 | Edit Account - Add name | 2 | VersionComment2 | Edit Account - Add name |

...

2.Pivot

See example

```
with UserAtr as(
  select * 
  from (select AccountNo,UserName,cast(VersionNo as varchar(10))VersionNo,VersionComment
    ,row_number()over(partition by AccountNo order by [Date])rn
    ,[date]
  from #Account
  ) a
  cross apply (values(concat('UserName',a.rn),a.UserName)
        ,(concat('VersionNo',a.rn),concat('Version #',a.VersionNo,'-',[date]))
        ,(concat('VersionComment',a.rn),a.VersionComment)
  )t(AtrName,AtrValue)
)

SELECT AccountNo,   
  UserName1, UserName2, UserName3, UserName20
  ,isnull(VersionNo1,'def1') VersionNo1, isnull(VersionNo2,'def2') VersionNo2
  ,isnull(VersionNo3,'def3') VersionNo3, isnull(VersionNo20,'def20') VersionNo20
  ,isnull(VersionComment1,'Def value1') VersionComment1
  ,isnull(VersionComment2,'Def value2') VersionComment2
  ,isnull(VersionComment3,'Def value3') VersionCommnet3
  ,isnull(VersionComment20,'Def value20') VersionComment20
FROM (
  SELECT AccountNo, AtrName,AtrValue   
  FROM UserAtr
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  min(AtrValue)  
  FOR AtrName IN (UserName1, UserName2, UserName3,UserName20
              ,VersionNo1,VersionNo2,VersionNo3,VersionNo20
      ,VersionComment1,VersionComment2,VersionComment3,VersionComment20
  )  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Output

| AccountNo | UserName1 | UserName2 | UserName3 | UserName20 | VersionNo1 | VersionNo2 | VersionNo3 | VersionNo20 | Version Comment1 | Version Comment2 | Version Comment3 | Version Comment20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | User | Admin | null | Version #1-2024-03-01 12:00:00.00 | Version #2-2024-03-02 08:00:00.00 | Version #3-2024-03-02 11:00:00.00 | def20 | New Account Edit | Account - Add name | Edit Account - Fix name | Def value20 |
| 2 | Admin | null | null | null | Version #1-2024-03-02 14:00:00.00 | def2 | def3 | def20 | New Account | Def value2 | Def value3 | Def value20 |
| 3 | User | Admin | null | null | Version #1-2024-03-03 08:00:00.00 | Version #2-2024-03-03 12:00:00.00 | def3 | def20 | New Account | Edit Account - Add website url | Def value3 | Def value20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UDod4a7v)