How can I put multiple values from one column spread out into multiple columns?
The table looks like this now;



CompanyLocationName
LineName




CompanyA
Auto


CompanyA
Home


CompanyA
Life


CompanyB
Auto



Is there a way to alter the query to make the table look like this?



CompanyLocationName
LineName
LineName2
LineName3




CompanyA
Auto
Home
Life


CompanyB
Auto
null
null



Basically if a CompanyLocationName has multiple LineNames, i would like them spread out into multiple columns like LineName2, LineName3, LineName4, etc. If a CompanyLocationName does not have extra LineNames to fill those extra columns, it will just show up as null

Please replace images with formatted text and also tag your DBMS.

I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Please tag the actual DBMS you are using.  Some have PIVOT operators and others don't.

@Isolated I have fixed it now thank you

Your DBMS is not [tag:ssms-19], that is just the tool you use to connect; you're using SQL Server ([tag:sql-server]), though you may also want to add a tag for the version you're using.

This is called pivot, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521138/group-by-column-and-merge-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-multiple-columns for one example. You need to have a way of sorting the rows somehow, sql server doesn't know what's line 1,2,3 etc.

You need to pivot the rows into columns. In SQL Server, you can do this using a max case method or by using the PIVOT operator (depending on your version).
In either case, you will need a key to enforce the order of the lines. In the below example I am using row_number() to create this based on the table order, but you likely have this column in your table already.
declare @YourTable table (RowId int identity(1,1) primary key, CompanyLocationName varchar(100), LineName varchar(100));
insert into @YourTable
    values
    ('CompanyA', 'Auto'),
    ('CompanyA', 'Home'),
    ('CompanyA', 'Life'),
    ('CompanyB', 'Auto')



-- using a "max case" to pivot the rows to columns
select  CompanyLocationName, 
        max(iif(r=1, LineName, null)) as LineName, 
        max(iif(r=2, LineName, null)) as LineName2, 
        max(iif(r=3, LineName, null)) as LineName3
from (  select CompanyLocationName, LineName, [r]= row_number()over(partition by CompanyLocationName order by RowId)
        from @YourTable
) as d
group
by CompanyLocationName;



-- using the PIVOT operator
select  CompanyLocationName, 
        [1] as LineName,
        [2] as LineName2,
        [3] as LineName3
from (  select CompanyLocationName, LineName, [r]= row_number()over(partition by CompanyLocationName order by RowId)
        from @YourTable
) as d
pivot(max(LineName) for r in ([1], [2], [3])) as p;

Returns:
CompanyLocationName LineName    LineName2   LineName3
CompanyA            Auto        Home        Life
CompanyB            Auto        NULL        NULL

